# Prevent user from sliding the map to the right or left

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there anyway to prevent user from sliding the map to the extreme right or left?  something like setting a maximum/minimum zoom level in arcgis maps.

Answer (score 1):

There are some code examples in this [thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/27971-Constrain-Map-Extent?highlight=limit%20extent) in the ArcGIS forums.

They involve setting the initial extent and using Extent.contains to check whether the new extent is within the initial extent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement onExtendChange event handler. Something like:

1. define the desired map limits x_min, x_max
2. onExtentChange event read the current extent
3. if x < x_min or y < y_min, setExtent accordingly